# Importing multiple Orocos/ROS packages in an RTT .ops script

Tags: ros, orocos

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recently refactored some Orocos/RTT components into a couple different ROS packages. I have an Orocos .ops script for testing each collection of components separately, but when I create a third package for testing integration, and combine the contents of the two other .ops scripts, they no longer run without segfaulting.

The odd thing is that it complains about one or the other library as being already loaded, and says "try to RELOAD":

```
3.834 [ Warning][DeploymentComponent::import] Library /home/jbohren/versioned/ros/bard/bard_controllers/lib/orocos/xenomai/libcomponents-xenomai.so already loaded... try to RELOAD
```

then it's the other library which causes a segfault on import:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffe7876910 in ?? () from /home/jbohren/versioned/ros/bard/bard_simulation/lib/orocos/xenomai/libcomponents-xenomai.so
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007fffe7876910 in ?? ()
   from /home/jbohren/versioned/ros/bard/bard_simulation/lib/orocos/xenomai/libcomponents-xenomai.so
#1  0x00007ffff73140ef in OCL::ComponentLoader::loadComponent (this=<value optimized out>, name=..., type=...)
    at /home/jbohren/versioned/ros/orocos_toolchain/ocl/deployment/ComponentLoader.cpp:641
#2  0x00007ffff728e90e in OCL::DeploymentComponent::loadComponent (this=0x7fffffffd590, name=..., type=...)
    at /home/jbohren/versioned/ros/orocos_toolchain/ocl/deployment/DeploymentComponent.cpp:1531
#3  0x00007ffff72c75d4 in boost::function2<bool, std::string const&, std::string const&>::operator() (
    this=<value optimized out>, t1=..., t2=...) at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1013
#4  call_impl<std::string const&, std::string const&> (this=<value optimized out>, t1=..., t2=...)
    at /home/jbohren/versioned/ros/orocos_toolchain/install/include/rtt/internal/../internal/LocalOperationCaller.hpp:386
#5  RTT::internal::InvokerImpl<2, bool ()(std::string const&, std::string const&), RTT::internal::LocalOperationCallerImpl<bool ()(std::string const&, std::string const&)> >::call(std::string const&, std::string const&) (this=<value optimized out>, 
    t1=..., t2=...) at /home/jbohren/versioned/ros/orocos_toolchain/install/include/rtt/internal/../internal/Invoker.hpp:125
```

Is anyone familiar with problems arising from factoring and combining components from multiple ros packages in a single orocos script?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31795/importing-multiple-orocos/ros-packages-in-an-rtt-.ops-script/) by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5809 on 2012-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out this was happening because the component libraries had the same name even though they were in different paths. I was still using the default name for the libraries in each CMakeLists.txt file, ie:

pkg_one/CMakeLists.txt:

```
...
orocos_component(components src_1.cpp src_2.cpp)
...
```

pkg_two/CMakeLists.txt:

```
...
orocos_component(components src_3.cpp src_4.cpp)
...
```

So giving these unique names solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1